# How to add an object on an array wthout to delete the rest with firestore?

Tags: ios, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add an object on my  array. My model already exist he is like that :

```
function createUser () {
  
      // User is signed in.
      firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .doc(user.uid)
  .set({
      NickName: nickName,
      Age: age,
      City:city,
      Mail:mail,
      Picture:'',
      MyTeam:[{
          Activity:"",
          City:"",
          adress:"",
          text:"",
          Members:[{
            Picture:"",
              Mail:"",
              Pseudo:""
          }],
      Owner:true
      }]
```

On the object "my team" i wanna be able to add few teams (like an array) but when i try to set, all my models is removed.

```
async function RegisterTeam () {
        // User is signed in.
        firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(await AsyncStorage.getItem ('userID'))
    .set({
        MyTeam:[{
            Activity:activity,
            City:city,
            Adress:adress,
            text: text,
            members: members,


        Owner:true
        }]
  
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('team created !')
                
            
            })         
        }
```

Do you have any idea how i can do that ?? i'm on react native ios

Answer (score 1):

You may use `.update()` instead of `.set()`. And to not overwrite the whole object you should use **dot notation** like this

```
firestore()
.collection('Users')
.doc(await AsyncStorage.getItem ('userID'))
.update({
  "MyTeam.newTeamObj": {newObj}
})
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Comment: thank you, your method is good, do you know how i can do if i want to create an ohter object on MyTeam without to delete the other one ?

Comment: yes. you can do so with the `arrayUnion()` method.
`.firestore()
.collection('Users')
.doc(await AsyncStorage.getItem ('userID'))
.update({
  MyTeam: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newObj)
})`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to use sub-collections here and not a arrays. In this case you will have:

```
users (collection)
    |
    ---------- teams (sub-collection) 
                 |
                 ------------ members (sub-sub-collection)
```